# When I define a variable in a game loop and a function in the gameloop after that

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am writing a game in python using pygame. I make some variables and a some in my game loop and then a function in my game loop

here is the important part of the code:

```
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()


white=(255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)



display_width=800
display_hieght=600


gameDisplay= pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_hieght))
pygame.display.set_caption('slither')







clock=pygame.time.Clock()
font=pygame.font.SysFont(None,25)

lead_x_change = 0
lead_y_change = 0

def message_to_screen(msg,colour,x,y):
    screen_text = font.render(msg,True,colour)
    gameDisplay.blit(screen_text,[x,y])
def gameloop():
    gameExit = False
    gameOver = False
    lead_x = display_width / 2
    lead_y = display_hieght - 5
    blocksize=int(10)
    FPS = 100
    score=0

    def shoot(event):
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if pos >= (590, 400):
            lead_x_change += 1
            lead_y_change += 0.1
        if pos >= (590, 400) and pos <= (580, 0):
            lead_x_change += 1
            lead_y_change += 0.2

    while not gameExit:
        pygame.display.update()
        while gameOver == True:
            gameDisplay.fill(white)
            message_to_screen('Game over, press Y to play again or N to quit',red,display_width*0.25,display_hieght/2)
            pygame.display.update()

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key== pygame.K_n:
                        gameExit = True
                        gameOver = False

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
            if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                   shoot(pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP)




        if lead_x >display_width -50:
            lead_x=display_width - 50
        elif lead_x <0:
            lead_x=0

        lead_x += lead_x_change
        lead_y += lead_y_change



        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        block=pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,red,(lead_x,lead_y,50,5))
        obj=pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay,black,(425,595),blocksize)
        pygame.Rect(block)
        pygame.Rect(obj)



        message_to_screen('score='+str(score),black,0,0)

        pygame.display.update()


    clock.tick(FPS)


    pygame.quit()
    quit()
gameloop()
```

in this code it says the variable `lead_x_change` and `lead_y_change` in the shoot function are not referenced yet.

Comment: Please show us the complete code. I wouldn't recommend to use global variables without a reason and rather pass the needed arguments to the function.

Answer (score 0):

`lead_x_change` and `lead_y_change` are local variables to the `gameloop` function and can only be accessed within that function. The `shoot` function cannot access them, which is what the `+=` operator is trying to do.

If you want `shoot` to have access, one solution is to make them global variables.

```
lead_x_change = 0    # global variable
lead_y_change = 0    # global variable

def gameloop():
    gameExit = False
    gameOver = False
    lead_x = display_width / 2
    lead_y = display_hieght - 5
    blocksize=int(10)
    FPS = 100
    score=0

def shoot(event):
    global lead_x_change, lead_y_change
    # Variable in global scope can be only read by a function, unless specially declared as global (above)
    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if pos >= (590, 400):
        lead_x_change += 1
        lead_y_change += 0.1
    if pos >= (590, 400) and pos <= (580, 0):
        lead_x_change += 1
        lead_y_change += 0.2
```

See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#global) on the `global` keyword.